# How to get list of Sabre Traveler Profiles using EPS_EXT_ProfileSearchRQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap, sabre

I'm using the EPS_EXT_ProfileSearchRQ Sabre API, trying to gather a list of profile references (TPA_Identities) for a given Corporate Profile. My payloads are below (redacted) - all I am getting back is the corporate profile itself, not the traveler level references, despite indicating the ProfileTypeCode of "TVL".

What am I getting wrong with this request?

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Sabre_OTA_ProfileSearchRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="6.46" ReturnPaymentCardToken="Y">
  <ProfileSearchCriteria ProfileNameOnly="Y" ReturnCount="250" xmlns="http://www.sabre.com/eps/schemas">
    <TPA_Identity ProfileTypeCode="TVL" ClientCode="TN" ClientContextCode="TMP" ProfileName="COMPANY NAME" DomainID="XX12" />
    <CustomerReferenceInfo />
  </ProfileSearchCriteria>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Sabre_OTA_ProfileSearchRS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" TimeStamp="2019-06-08T19:19:31.529Z" Version="6.51">
  <ResponseMessage xmlns="http://www.sabre.com/eps/schemas">
    <Success />
  </ResponseMessage>
  <ProfileInfo xmlns="http://www.sabre.com/eps/schemas">
    <Profile CreateDateTime="2018-03-30T20:51:31.386Z" UpdateDateTime="2018-04-18T15:33:08.904Z" PrimaryLanguageIDCode="EN-US">
      <TPA_Identity ClientCode="TN" ClientContextCode="MYS" UniqueID="6164723212" ProfileTypeCode="TVL" ProfileName="COMPANY NAME" ProfileNameModifyIndicator="Y" ProfileDescription="COMPANY NAME" DomainID="XX12" ProfileStatusCode="AC">
        <ProfileSubType SubTypeCode="NN" />
      </TPA_Identity>
      <Traveler>
        <Customer ChildIndicator="N" SeniorIndicator="N" LapInfantIndicator="N" IsSubjectToSecureFlightRule="N">
          <Email EmailTypeCode="UNK" EmailAddress="SPETERSON@COMPANYNAME.COM" OrderSequenceNo="1" />
          <Address LocationTypeCode="BUS" Attention="COMPANY NAME" OrderSequenceNo="1">
            <AddressLine>5331 XXXX STREET</AddressLine>
            <CityName>ROGER</CityName>
            <PostalCd>81205</PostalCd>
            <StateCode>AK</StateCode>
          </Address>
          <CustLoyalty VendorTypeCode="CR" VendorCode="ZI" MembershipID="X1A87DG" OrderSequenceNo="1" />
        </Customer>
        <TPA_Extensions>
          <CustomerReferenceInfo TripTypeCode="AZ" BranchID="CMI" ReferenceID="888" OrderSequenceNo="1" />
          <STARData STARName="COMPANY NAME" OrderSequenceNo="1"></STARData>
        </TPA_Extensions>
      </Traveler>
    </Profile>
  </ProfileInfo>
</Sabre_OTA_ProfileSearchRS>
```

Comment: Looks like the response is for ClientCode="TN".  Maybe that is the only trip the client made.

Comment: TN in this context means "Travel Network", which is the term to describe Travel Agencies consuming Sabre Web Services.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you have built your Profiles structure. If you are looking for all of the Traveler profiles that are associated to the "COMPANY NAME" corporate profile, you could use something like this:

```
<Sabre_OTA_ProfileSearchRQ xmlns="http://www.sabre.com/eps/schemas" xmlns:ns2="http://services.sabre.com/res/tir/v3_9" xmlns:ns3="http://services.sabre.com/res/or/v1_9" xmlns:ns4="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" xmlns:ns5="http://webservices.sabre.com/triprecord" xmlns:ns6="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_19" xmlns:ns7="http://services.sabre.com/res/or/v1_14" TimeStamp="2019-06-10T17:04:53.879+08:00" Version="6.35">
        <ProfileSearchCriteria CountAll="Y" PageNumber="1" ReturnCount="50" SearchOperationType="AND">
            <TPA_Identity ClientCode="TN" ClientContextCode="TMP" DomainID="XX12" ProfileName="*" ProfileTypeCode="TVL"/>
            <AssociatedProfiles AssocProfileName="COMPANY NAME" IncludeTemplateAssoc="Y"/>
            <SortPreference SortByCreateDate="N" SortByProfileName="Y"/>
        </ProfileSearchCriteria>
    </Sabre_OTA_ProfileSearchRQ>
```

Bear in mind that the request is also looking for profiles that are associated within the template, if that's available, with IncludeTemplateAssoc="Y". So, this search will look for all of your TVL profiles, given they are associated to that particular CRP profile, through the profiles themselves or through an association object (template).

Comment: Yahtzee! Thank you so much, that worked perfectly. The verbiage that Sabre Profiles uses is confusing to me since Im a legacy Sabre Red user, so if anyone else is having an issue with this, the value that should be passed into the AssocProfileName is the CRP level profile name, not the Template name. It also must match exactly (or at least it did for me). Anyhow, thanks again.